# Move Fedora VM to Google Cloud

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, fedora, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have a VM that runs an old version of Fedora ( Fedora 9 to be exact ). I need to support this platform as it still runs some applications.

Can anyone please guide on how to migrate this VM to the google cloud platform? Is this even possible?

I have checked the following link:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks

But the article seems to suggest that Fedora VM's may not be supported. if not possible with GCP, would this be possible with azure or AWS?

Any pointers in the rifght direction to approach the problem would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible to do this using the AWS platform. On the AWS platform, we can create custom AMI Images, and launch instances using those Images.

However the migration is restricted to a couple of pre-approved Images. Check the following link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html